Hashing type for file contents
I need to name a file after its contents as a way to prevent duplicates. The files are images, and prior to saving a new file I check my media library table for duplicate names.
So I use hash_file. But I am wondering about the encryption.
md5, sha1, sha256, something else?
I know md5 is quickest and sha256 is less likely to collide, but sha256 produces very long filenames.
In the real world scenario of user uploaded images on a website, which one is best?

Having a look at this hash speed benchmark can be useful.

rmd160 gives a 40 hex char hash and there are no known collisions as of Nov 2024.

What if two users happen to upload identical files?

If you don't want collisions, add metadata to the filename. Even just appending the file's length is enough to reduce the already-infinitesimal collision domain by orders of magnitude.

Do you only care about exact bit-for-bit duplicates? What should happen if I toggle one pixel and re-upload?

hashing IS NOT encrypting!

md5 is fine as long as you're not worried about malicious users generating collisions on purpose, and (using a birthday paradox calculator) the risk of a natural collision seems low enough.
If you want to reduce this risk use a better hash. Not sure why you would care about filename length. It's not like you're going to manually type these.

thanks - so perhaps sha256?

@panthro yes, well part of my answer is basically: You understand your own requirements better than I can. md5 is fast, cheap, short. if you don't have real reservations against sa256 then sure do that!

Well, I would not allow users to upload files, if they aren't registered users and logged in. If this is the case, create a subfolder for each user with the same username which has to be unique. Then a combination of a timestamp and md5 would do it. Combine the timestamp and the md5 with an underscore between. So it's easy to chop off the timestamp to compare for the image already being present. At least, that's how I would do it.

Good start panthro,
You could salt the hash in a couple of ways:

Like how Aranxo is surmising, add the date_created to the filename and then the hash after, maybe with or without some delineator.
Keep the filename, create some sort of hash (MD5, sha256, etc), and then truncate the hash to a length where it and the filename are constant across all records.

Point two could be more interesting, since it would stop the collision case in Aranxo's answer where two MD5 hashes collide at the same time, making the timestamps equal (down to the lowest integer) and the MD5 hashes equal.
HPC might see this use case for large(n) file storage requests.
Also, point two would implicitly enforce a character limit on the filename length, which could prevent malicious or accidental failures on the system.
Salting the hash more, with perhaps additional metadata like IP where the request was made, or even the username if the user agrees to this in a Privacy Policy.

You got a lot wrong here. To start with, the point of the OP's scheme is to detect and prevent duplicates. There's no need or benefit to "salting" this hash, and that's not what @aranxo is proposing.

Ah, I see. I think I was just defending that by increasing the size of each record's hash length in characters, perhaps by adding more encrypted values, you would very much prevent duplicates. My original understanding is that may be a form of salting in cryptography? I may be mistaken here, please correct me if I'm not correct.
